# Why is the Uninstall-ChocolateyPackage cmdlet not recognized?

Tags: powershell, chocolatey

I am trying to run a PowerShell script to uninstall `owncloud-client` from my Windows 10 virtual machine. The code shown below can be found at

https://chocolatey.org/packages/owncloud-client (tools\chocolateyUninstall.ps1)

I would like just to test the code by running it from PowerShell to see if it actually uninstalls the software.

```
$unfile = "ownCloud\uninstall.exe"

if (Test-Path "${Env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\$unfile") {
  $unpath = "${Env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\$unfile"
} else {
  $unpath = "${Env:ProgramFiles}\$unfile"
}

Uninstall-ChocolateyPackage 'owncloud-client' 'exe' '/S' "$unpath"
```

I run script from the directory that contains it by typying:

```
.\chocolateyUninstall.ps1
```

As output I get the following error:

```
Uninstall-ChocolateyPackage  is not recognized as the name of cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
```

The Uninstall-ChocolateyPacakge.ps1 package is provided by chocolatey. I checked on my machine and this package is present under:

```
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\helpers\functions\Uninstall-ChocolateyPackage.ps1
```

but still it is not recognized as cmdlet by powershell. How can I solve this problem? thanks

Comment: I am not familiar with this at all so I recommend you put more details in your question. What are you trying to run? `Uninstall-ChocolateyPackage`? Or `Uninstall -ChocolateyPackage`?

Comment: I tried them both, none of them works. The on that should work is  `Uninstall-ChocolateyPackage`

Comment: It very very confusing to me what steps you're taking, what scripts you're running, and which give you the errors.

Comment: @slybloty check the edit. I am running the all script I posted and I get the error you see below it.

Comment: The error tells you that `Uninstall-ChocolateyPackage` is not defined anywhere. Aren't you supposed to be running `chocolateyUninstall`? Again, you need to better explain what you're doing. What is `Uninstall-ChocolateyPackage`? And where is it?

Comment: @slybloty check the edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When running the installation/uninstallation scripts, Chocolatey first includes the Chocolatey PowerShell module.  This is done in the background, and normally, the end user doesn't need to worry about it.

For what you are trying to do, you will need to first do an `Import-Module` on the Chocolatey module, to bring it into the current PowerShell session.  You can find this here:

old: `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\chocolatey\tools\chocolateyInstall\helpers\chocolateyInstaller.psm1`

new: `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\helpers\chocolateyInstaller.psm1`

That should allow you to test the script directly.

Alternatively, you could run the install of the package, and then run the uninstall to see if it works as well.

Comment: In case anyone finds this via Google, the path is now updated to `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\helpers\chocolateyInstaller.psm1`.

Answer (score 1):

With the latest moderation tools, you don't need to check every package (I mean, unless it makes you feel safer). You can always check the automated tests. There's a status dot to the right of the package title.

[image]

You can find the test summary

> owncloud-client v2.1.1.5837 - Passed - Package Test Results
>
> https://chocolatey.org/packages/owncloud-client/2.1.1.5837
>   Tested 10 Feb 2016 12:51:22 +00:00
>   Tested against win2012r2x64 (Windows Server 2012 R2 x64)
>   Tested with the latest version of choco, possibly a beta version.
>   Tested with chocolatey-package-verifier service v0.4.0-15-g979d0cc
>   Install was successful.
>   Uninstall was successful.

https://gist.github.com/choco-bot/45f343e23cc12e101130#file-_summary-md

or explore the uninstall log directly.

https://gist.github.com/choco-bot/45f343e23cc12e101130#file-uninstall-txt

Comment: And, if you are really keen, you can use a local version of the package verifier, from here: https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey-test-environment

Comment: **NOTE:** Currently, the package verifier doesn't failing packages on erroring during uninstallation, only installation.  This will change at some point though.